# Failure while building llgo+llvm

Tags: go, clang, llvm

I was trying to build the llvm project from the sources. I'm interested in using (instrumenting) the go frontend. I followed steps from [llgo repo](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llgo). It fails when executing

> make install

at 91%.

```
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/dsymutil
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/CMakeFiles/obj.clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.dir/VforkChecker.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaStmt.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaStmtAsm.cpp.o
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
tools/llc/CMakeFiles/llc.dir/build.make:212: recipe for target 'bin/llc' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/llc] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'bin/llc'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68154: recipe for target 'tools/llc/CMakeFiles/llc.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/llc/CMakeFiles/llc.dir/all] Error 2
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/CMakeFiles/obj.clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.dir/VLASizeChecker.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaStmtAttr.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/CMakeFiles/obj.clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.dir/ValistChecker.cpp.o
[ 91%] Built target llvm-cfi-verify
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/CMakeFiles/obj.clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.dir/VirtualCallChecker.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaTemplate.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaTemplateDeduction.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaTemplateInstantiate.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaTemplateInstantiateDecl.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaTemplateVariadic.cpp.o
[ 91%] Built target obj.clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/SemaType.cpp.o
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
tools/bugpoint/CMakeFiles/bugpoint.dir/build.make:419: recipe for target 'bin/bugpoint' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/bugpoint] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'bin/bugpoint'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67602: recipe for target 'tools/bugpoint/CMakeFiles/bugpoint.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/bugpoint/CMakeFiles/bugpoint.dir/all] Error 2
[ 91%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Sema/CMakeFiles/obj.clangSema.dir/TypeLocBuilder.cpp.o
[ 91%] Built target obj.clangSema
[ 91%] Built target dsymutil
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Alternatively, I followed [building clang 8, llvm 8 on ubuntu 18.04](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/01/17/building-clang-libcpp-ubuntu-linux/). I managed to build clang+llvm. I tried to build llgo but failed terribly. What am I missing?

I'm  using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to lack RAM for linking. Try running `make` without `-j` argument, switching `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Release` and using `gold` or `lld` instead of BFD `ld`.